# Fast find exist in list or not

Tags: java, array, search

I want to determine whether or not the selected element exists in the list. This is the current procedure that I'm using for finding the element exist in a list or array. Is there any fast procedure for finding an element with any of these?

```
int[] array = { 1,2,9,3,5,6,7,8,10};

boolean isFound = false;
for(int i =0; i< array.length;i++) {
    if(array[i] == 4 || array[i] == 9) {
      isFound = true;
      break;
    }
}
System.out.println(isFound);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention anything about the array length.

In this kind of problems the length is a key that lead to the proper solution.

In your example, the algorithm you're using is the faster, because anything else will need more resources that need time to be allocated and initialized.

The situation is different if you have an array with millions of elements.

In this case you could find a different pattern to cut the time of searching.

For example you could break the array in chunks and then search on parallel with threads.

Use the *Arrays.binarySearch()*, that need the array to be sorted.

But again, all this stuff is wort to be used only if you works with very huge arrays.

The best thing is to set up few tests that could give you a comparison about all the different approach, or how your algorithm degrade with the increasing of the array size.

Answer (score 2):

This strictly depends on the use case. If your list:

- Doesn't change
- Holds a lot of data
- Is being searched many times
- And you don't care about **where** the element is

Then it **may** be worth keeping a cached sorted copy of the list and using `Arrays.binarySearch()` on it.

If those conditions are not met, then you're better off just doing a linear search. Of course you can't go lower than O(n) time, because you have to check every element if the list is not sorted.

Comment: Of course you _can't_ go lower than O(n) time _overall_, but if you build the array once and then search it multiple times and you can afford O(n log n) time for allocating a copy of the array and sorting it prior to regular use, then you _can_ go down to O(log n) per _each search_.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithms that involve searching for elements that exist in a list require you to **traverse through the list**. So the fastest way possible is just to iterate through the list as what you did.

The time complexity of such algorithm would run in `O(n)` time where n is the size/length of your list. So, how fast you want your algorithm to be depends on the size of your list. The smaller it is, the faster it runs and vice versa.

I wrote a method that achieves the same result using `java.util.List` and `java.util.Arrays`.

```
  boolean isFound(int elem) {
    List<Integer> arrList = Arrays.asList(1,2,9,3,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    if (arrList.contains(elem)) return true;
    else return false;
  }
```

It is shorter and more readable in my opinion. However, would still run in `O(n)` because:

> The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run
>   in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time,
>   that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other
>   operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor
>   is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html